AWS amplify: how to distinguish a generation 1 project from a newer generation 2?
I received a project to mantain.
What can help me to understand if this is a Generation 1 or a Generation 2 project?

Both Gen1 and Gen2 projects has a amplify directory on the root of the project.

For Gen1, this amplify directory, contains CloudFormation templates (JSON files)
For Gen2, this amplify directory, contains CDK code written in TypeScript files.

Directory structure of an Amplify Gen2 app's amplify folder would be something like below image.

For more detail, refer to these repositories:

Gen1 - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js-samples
Gen2 - https://github.com/aws-samples/amplify-next-template

